# How to align carets vertically centered with text in breadcrumbs?

Tags: html, css

I have this breadcrumbs:

[image: sample]

As you can see right carets are stay at top. Not aligned with text vertically. I tried giving them `padding`, `top`, `margin` but none of them worked.

```css
body {
  font-family: "Open Sans", "Segoe UI", Halvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.breadcrumbs {
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
ol, ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}
.item {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #848c98;
}

.item:not(:last-child):after {
    font-family: "Ionicons";
    margin: 0 .625rem;
    color: #a1a7af;
    content: "\f3d1";
}
```

```html
<link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<ol class="breadcrumbs">
    <li class="item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="item"><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li class="item"><a href="#">Team</a></li>
    <li class="item is-active">Last</li>
</ol>
```

See Live Alternative: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MxzGXo

How can I give them a padding on top so they align vertically with text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to want to vertically align the carat:

https://codepen.io/jgoncalves/pen/OqaZeN

```css
body {
  font-family: "Open Sans", "Segoe UI", Halvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.breadcrumbs {
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
ol, ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}
.item {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #848c98;
}

.item:not(:last-child):after {
    font-family: "Ionicons";
    margin: 0 .625rem;
    color: #a1a7af;
    content: "\f3d1";
    vertical-align: middle; /* this is new */
}
```

```html
<ol class="breadcrumbs">
    <li class="item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="item"><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li class="item"><a href="#">Team</a></li>
    <li class="item is-active">Last</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Aha! This did not come to my mind, Ever. Thank you so much! _(I will mark this as accepted after delay. SO do not allow me to accept it yet.)_